# Python .cgi script - creating HTML button dynamically - Cannot pass onclick function parameter

Tags: python, html, parameters, onclick, dynamically-generated

For some reason **I can** create an HTML button dynamically in python with an onclick that has a function **without any parameters**. However, **when I add a parameter** and click the live button online I get this error in the console:

```
ReferenceError: Can't find variable: thing
onclick - script element 1:1
```

the "script element 1:1" is a link which brings me to another portion of the console and shows me this:

```
function onclick(event) {
doTheThing(thing)
}
```

However, the actual function I wrote in javascript looks like this:

```
function doTheThing(thing){
    console.log(thing);
}
```

This is the HTML button I have created dynamically with python:

```
for thing in things:
    print "<button type = 'button' onclick = 'doTheThing("+thing+")' class = 'button'>"
    print "Button that does things"
    print "</button>"
```

I don't understand why I cant pass a parameter and it works without a parameter.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend 1 of 2 things:

1. Pass the event into `doTheThing` from the `onClick` Function, instead of passing it `thing` value, which that scope shouldn't be aware of.

   - From the error, it looks like it's trying to call `doTheThing` via the onClick function you have defined there, overriding the default JS onClick function.

Something like this may help you get a bit farther:

```
function onclick(event) {
doTheThing(event)
}
```

2. Try deleting your onClick function, which would be overriding the default JS onClick function & its behavior.

Comment: Sorry friend, I guess I wasn't that clear. I never created the onclick function with the event, its only something that is shown from the error. Im not even sure how to override that function. Anywho this seems strange that I cant dynamically create buttons with specific function params. I remember running into this issue in dynamically creating buttons in javascript alone, but I solved it with `plusButton.onclick = function() {
        plusClicked(productNumber);
    };` instead of `plusButton.onclick = plusClicked(productNumber);`

Comment: Would really wish if someone had some insight in dynamically creating buttons with function params in python

Comment: Do you have the source code to add to the intial post? I definitely have experience with this in other languages, so it may transfer to Python. Think it would help others (with familiarity in Python, or otherwise) as well!